# Sharepoint 2013 Notifications (Similar to Outlook)

Tags: javascript, notifications

I have a SharePoint 2013 on-premise intranet portal. I want to build a Notifications feature similar to the one in Office 365 or something similar. Anyone got recommendations on using 3rd libraries (like angular, knockoutJS or JS frameworks).

[image]

Comment: Have you got solution/implemented to this?? If so, please share the way u implemented..

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/80672)